# Assigning Year, Month and Day Variables in perl -lne

Tags: sh

Simple newbie question that seems to be stumping me. 
I've looked at other topics and resources and I'm not seeing the simple answer.

I'm running a very simple (perl -lne) command that helps me query specific data out of a pwebstats output , and output into a linear .csv file format for my reports.

The question is this:

Is there a quick, and clean way of assigning variables for the file name, Year , Month and Day ( i.e allowing the person running the command to simply enter the File Name ($FILENAME) , Year ($YEAR), Month ($MONTH) and Day ($DAY) and the execute without having to alter the perl -lne command each time?)

EXAMPLE OF COMMAND :

```
zcat /opt/log/file/$Year/$Month/$FILENAME/sm/$FILENAME.$Year-$Month-$Day \
   | perl -lne '/.{0,0}FILENAME PAX Total HTTP IP Packet Count.{0,6}/ && print $&' \
       > /tmp/jhoney/$FILENAME-IPcountTMP.csv

zcat /opt/log/file/$Year/$Month/$FILENAME/sm/$FILENAME.$Year-$Month-$Day \
    | perl -lne '/.{0,0}PAX HTTP Average TCP RTT.{0,20}/ && print $&' \
        > /tmp/jhoney/$FIELNAME-TCPrttTMP.csv

paste -d , /tmp/jhoney/$FILENAME-IPcountTMP.csv /tmp/jhoney/$FILENAME-TCPrttTMP.csv \
    > /tmp/jhoney/$FILENAME-PAXdata.csv

rm -r /tmp/jhoney/$FILENAME-TCPrttTMP.csv /tmp/jhoney/$FILENAME-IPcountTMP.csv
```

I know the answer is looking right in my face, but, I'm learning perl and pyhton as I go.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please explain, or show in context...

Comment: @ikegami This might be a shell question and they're asking how to set shell variables. Not sure, though.

Comment: @J.Honey, Could you be clearer as to what you want to assign to what?

Comment: @ikgami ..I think I'm asking for a quick and clean Shell Variable to run on top of the perl -lne, allowing a user to simply input the $Year, $Month, $Day, and $File Name.

Comment: @ikgami...something similar to a user just simpling entering the following : PAXStat.pl -f FILENAME -y 2015 -m 09 -d 06

Comment: @J.Honey What's `PAXStat.pl`?

Comment: @melpomene, I think the OP is referring to the `sh` commands. Same goes when he said "a very simple (perl -lne) command".

Answer (score 1):

What you keep calling a Perl command are `sh` commands. Parsing command line options in `sh` is not trivial. If you don't mind switching to positional parameters, it would be a lot simpler.

Usage:

```
PAXStat 2015 09 06 FILENAME
```

Script:

```
#!/bin/sh

Year=$1
Month=$2
Day=$3
FILENAME=$4

zcat /opt/log/file/$Year/$Month/$FILENAME/sm/$FILENAME.$Year-$Month-$Day \
   | perl -lne '/.{0,0}FILENAME PAX Total HTTP IP Packet Count.{0,6}/ && print $&' \
       > /tmp/jhoney/$FILENAME-IPcountTMP.csv

zcat /opt/log/file/$Year/$Month/$FILENAME/sm/$FILENAME.$Year-$Month-$Day \
    | perl -lne '/.{0,0}PAX HTTP Average TCP RTT.{0,20}/ && print $&' \
        > /tmp/jhoney/$FIELNAME-TCPrttTMP.csv

paste -d , /tmp/jhoney/$FILENAME-IPcountTMP.csv /tmp/jhoney/$FILENAME-TCPrttTMP.csv \
    > /tmp/jhoney/$FILENAME-PAXdata.csv

rm -r /tmp/jhoney/$FILENAME-TCPrttTMP.csv /tmp/jhoney/$FILENAME-IPcountTMP.csv
```

Comment: @ikegami...brilliant! Was staring me in the face entire time. I was just over thinking it. goes to show you, never trust a newbie like myself with no sleep for the past 24 hours!. @ikegami,..thank you again ol' chap!